# [Vue warn]: Property or method "permissionsSelected" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I'm trying to auto check active permissions, but vue does not work. Can someone explain what's the problem ? because im not wery experienced with this stuff.

Console Output:

> [Vue warn]: Property or method "permissionsSelected" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property. See: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Declaring-Reactive-Properties.

```
@extends('template.default')

@section('content')
<form action="{{ route('roles.update', $role->id) }}" method="POST">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    {{ method_field('PUT') }}
    <input type="hidden" :value="permissionsSelected" name="permissions">

    <h5>Permissions:</h5>
    @foreach ($permissions as $r)
        <el-checkbox v-model="permissionsSelected" :native-value="{{$r->id}}"> {{$r->display_name}} <em>({{$r->description}})</em></el-checkbox>
    @endforeach
</form>

@endsection

@section('scripts')
  <script>
  var app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
      permissionsSelected: {!! $role->permissions->pluck('id') !!}
    }
  });
  </script>
@endsection
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are initializing the Vue on `#app` but there is no element with that id.

Try adding an id to form:

`<form id="app" action="{{ route('roles.update', $role->id) }}" method="POST">`

EDIT: if you want to extend an already initialized Vue instance, use `Vue.extend`

EDIT2: when using laravel and blade templating, to avoid these kind of issues, I would instead use a [.vue file](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/single-file-components.html) with a [prop](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html) to get data inside the component and do what ever with that data inside it. In this way it is avoided multiple instantiations of Vue and the code is more granular and better structured.

Comment: there is an global id on template that this partial is extending

Comment: then I think you are missing the template part from. As in the error message, if you go to the documentation, you have 
`data: {
    // declare message with an empty value
    message: ''
  },
  template: '<div>{{ message }}</div>'`

Comment: Also, the script will not read above the template. Either use `Vue.extend` or add an element in this blade template with the id `app`.

Comment: i tried adding id on form = no effect. Didn't quite understand the first comment, but i tried using template, don't know if i done it right but still no effect.

Comment: checkout [tihs](https://jsfiddle.net/43vf3u41/3/) fiddle for a raw implementation. Adding `id="app"` works

Comment: @nullatonce please set as solution if it was helpful

Answer (score 0):

if you have a vue instance in app.js or in any shared js file, delete it @Leonardo H

Comment: a guy in the comments @Pierre.Vriens